# When does the Community bot bump posts, and how do I bump posts?

Tags: support, bumping, community-user

I apologize if this question is on a FAQ somewhere, but a cursory search turned up empty. I am trying to find out:

1. Under what conditions will the Community bot decide to bump my question onto the front page?
2. What actions that I do (editing, commenting, voting, posting an answer) cause a question to be bumped onto the front page?

I have never seen "bumping" in action before, but I usually look at "Questions > Newest", which may have something to do with that. Which of the pages is subject to such a bumping process, and (subjective question) what page do you usually look at if you are looking for new questions to answer?

Comment: You might have a look at [tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info) for the tag [meta-tag:bumping]. It contains list of actions which cause bumping.

Comment: @MartinSleziak So any edit, regardless how minor, will bump, and commenting never does?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Voting a post won't bump it either. As noted, the bot bumps up questions that have answers without any upvotes, usually starting 30 days after the question was posted.

Comment: @Ｊ.M. Does it matter if the non-upvoted answer is accepted or not? Also, can someone tell me what the "front page" *is*? I have no idea where this bumping takes place.

Comment: Ah, yes; questions with accepted answers will not be bumped by the bot. If you want to see the front page for the main site, go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/). The front page for the meta site is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Ｊ.M., isn't it the case that what OP will see on following your link depends on whether OP has the front page sorted by "Newest" or by "Active"? And doesn't bumping affect the latter, but not the former?

Comment: @Gerry, I see "active", "featured" (31 bounty questions ATM), "hot" (apparently the default view for unregistered users), "week" and "month", but no "newest", which would be [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). That last one's not the front page anymore, tho.

Comment: @Ｊ.M., of course you're right, I was in MO mode, where (I think) the options include "newest".

Comment: for the community user, see the recently posted question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13934/how-does-the-community-user-poke-questions